# Delete vertices from shapely geometry falling inside another geometry

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

```
import shapely.wkt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

---

I have 2 shapely geometries, `p` and `q`:

```
p = shapely.wkt.loads("POLYGON((1.4 0.7, 1.8 0.7, 1.8 1.1, 1.4 1.1, 1.4 0.7))") 
q = shapely.wkt.loads("MULTIPOLYGON(((1 0.5, 2 0.5, 1.6 0.85, 1 1, 1 1, 1 0.5),(1.5 0.9, 1.6 0.9, 1.6 1, 1.5 0.9)))")
```

[image]

(plot via: `gpd.GeoSeries([p,q]).plot(color=['r','b'],alpha=0.5)`)

**I would like to remove every vertex from `q` within `p`. How can I do that?**

Expected output is `r`, a shapely geometry:

```
r = shapely.wkt.loads("MULTIPOLYGON(((1 0.5, 2 0.5, 1 1, 1 1, 1 0.5)))")
```

Visualized (in yellow):

[image]

(via `gpd.GeoSeries([p,q,r]).plot(color=['r','b','y'],alpha=0.5)`)

Comment: Maybe here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613673/remove-a-polygon-from-a-multipolygon-with-shapely-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat tedious method:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon
r = MultiPolygon([Polygon([Point(xy) for xy in zip(*geom.exterior.xy) if not p.contains(Point(xy))]) for geom in q.geoms])
```